# Amazon Redshift: The DB is overriding created_at values with its own

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm using a copy command to load many files into the redshift DB. The redshift's own created_at is overriding the created_at timestamp specified in the json.

```
COPY test
FROM s3://test/test
credentials 'my credentials'
json 'auto';
```

An example would be:

The json being imported

```
{"foo":"bar", "created_at":"2018-09-05 17:48:34"}
```

This saves successfully in the DB, but the json timestamp is overwritten to the current time (ie 2018-09-10 16:00:28)

How can I make redshift respect the created_at times I am giving it?

Comment: do you have a default in your target table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is excerpt from Redshift official [documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading_default_values.html) to handle column with Default Value.

> If a column in the table is omitted from the column list, COPY will load the column with either the value supplied by the DEFAULT option that was specified in the CREATE TABLE command, or with NULL if the DEFAULT option was not specified.

So if you skip from column list, it will always save `DEFAULT`. And Default are only evaluated once, meaning all the rows will have same value.

**I believe this must not be your case**, the only possible culprit could be your `json 'auto'` which may be unintentionally making `Redshift`  ignore `created_at`.

Then, if you specify the DEFAULT column in, it always load it from your data file, so if you don't that records, it will consider it as `null` and load as `null`. Doesn't apply the logic of `DEFAULT`. For example if your data is like--

```
{"foo":"bar", "created_at":"2018-09-05 17:48:34"}
{"foo":"bar1","created_at":""}
{"foo":"bar2"}
{"foo":"bar3","created_at":null}
```

It will be populated to database like below.

```
 foo  |     created_at
------+---------------------
 bar2 |
 bar  | 2018-09-05 17:48:34
 bar1 |
 bar1 |
(4 rows)
```

SO what options you have to handle this situation?

Go with second option, where you specify the column with default values and issue an `update` query immediacy after loading your data. e.g.

```
 update foo set created_at= sysdate where created_at is null;
```

**Please keep in mind**, `UPDATEs` are costly operations in `Redshift` as its `DELETE+INSERT`. Then what else, if possible transform your data at the source if its not costly there Or do a comparison, where populating DEFAULT suites best in your case.

I hope it helps, if not, let me know via comment, I'll refocus the answer.

Comment: My problem ended up being a user error on my side. All was working correctly. This answer is a good one though, and should help out people with similar issues